# como colocar scroll correctamente?(react, material ui, mui datatable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

estoy utilizando mui-datatable para mostrar la informacion obtenida de una peticion. las opciones de mi tabla son:

````
const options = {
        print: false,
        download: false,
        filter: false,
        viewColumns: false,
        selectableRows: "none",
        responsive: "scroll", <-- estoy utilizando eso para el scroll
        rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, { label: 'All', value: data.length }]
        />
    };```
la tabla se llena bien y si funciona el scroll y todo, pero en la consola me arroja `Failed prop type: Invalid prop `options.responsive` of value `scroll` supplied to `a`, expected one of ["standard","vertical","verticalAlways","simple"]``` al sustituir el scroll con una de esas alternativas se soluciona este error pero el scroll desaparece
````

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial de MuI datatables tienes:
Solo 3 opciones para la propia responsive:
"vertical" (valor por defecto): En vistas pequeñas las celdas van a colapsar y mostrar la información en sub celdas verticales.
"standard": Ña tabla continuará en modo estándar pero realizará pequeños cambios para emplear mejor el espacio.
"simple": En dispositivos muy pequeños cada fila se colapsará en una pantalla.

La documentación oficial de la librería está disponible en https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables